# Filter 1 mysql row multiple ways in a php query

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter 1 row (sales_quantity) of a mysql table 3 different ways in a query.  I want to display the same row based on the last 7 days, 30 days, and 90 days.  I'm able to filter the entire query by one of these methods, but I can't figure out how to filter by 3 different methods in the same query.  Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT 
  titles.id, 
  titles.title, 
  titles.label, 
  titles.street_date, 
  titles.upc, 
  sales.upc, 
  SUM(sales.sales_quantity) AS sum_sales, 
  sales.invoice_date 
FROM 
  titles, 
  sales 
WHERE 
  titles.upc = sales.upc 
  AND titles.label='$user_partner' 
  AND sales.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
GROUP BY sales.upc 
ORDER BY sum_sales DESC LIMIT 30"; 

$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 

$title_list = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $title_id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $title_upc = $row["upc"];
    $street_date =$row["street_date"];
    $sales_upc = $row["upc"];
    $sales_quantity_7 = $row["sum_sales"];
        $sales_quantity_30 = $row["sum_sales"];
        $sales_quantity_90 = $row["sum_sales"];

    $title_list .= '<div class="list"><div class="title">'. $title.'</div><div class="upc">'.$title_upc.'</div><div class="date">'.$street_date.'</div><div class="sales">'.$sales_quantity_7.'</div><div class="sales">'.$sales_quantity_30.'</div><div class="sales">'.$sales_quantity_90.'</div></div>';
}
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Use subqueries in the `SELECT` for each summation.

Answer (score 2):

You can join against the same table three times if you use this format.  You need to create an alias for each of the `sales` tables and use appropriate `WHERE` clause criteria for each.  This should work, but it's hard to be certain without a database to test myself.

**EDIT:** Added a fourth plain `sales` alias since you had other columns in there.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT 
  titles.id, 
  titles.title, 
  titles.label, 
  titles.street_date, 
  titles.upc, 
  sales.upc, 
  SUM(sales_90.sales_quantity) AS sum_sales_90,
  SUM(sales_30.sales_quantity) AS sum_sales_30,
  SUM(sales_7.sales_quantity) AS sum_sales_7,
  sales.invoice_date 
FROM 
  titles
    JOIN sales sales ON titles.upc = sales.upc
    JOIN sales sales_90 ON titles.upc = sales_90.upc
    JOIN sales sales_30 ON titles.upc = sales_30.upc
    JOIN sales sales_7 ON titles.upc = sales_7.upc
WHERE 
  AND titles.label='$user_partner' 
  AND sales_90.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)
  AND sales_30.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND sales_7.invoice_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY sales.upc, sales_90.upc, sales_30.upc, sales_7.upc 
ORDER BY sum_sales_90 DESC LIMIT 30";
```